# Preparations for chess tournaments

Tags: tournament, elo, preparation

So I'm participating in a chess tournament in a few days (FIDE rating) and I'm in a fix as to preparation methods. I'm doing as many puzzles as I can and preparing many openings. I'm also playing few precursor tournaments for practice. But is there any specific approach I need to take? Like I need a 1500 plus rating for my next year's pocket money so is there anything you need to do to get to get an extra edge over the competition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sleep well and hit the gym.

Over the board is hard physically as well as mentally. And physical condition has big contribution to playing strength.

So in short, don't get tired before your opponent, be the last man standing.